# Como tomar valores desde el header, laravel, para guardar archivos?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

Tengo el siguiente metodo para subir imagenes desde el front:

```
public function subirAdjunto(Request $request,$id_adjunto) {
        if($request->file('archivo'))
        {
            $validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'v_palabras_clave'=>'required',
                'archivo'=> 'required|mimes:docx,pdf,png,jpg,jpeg|max:' . AtAdjuntoInterno::TAMANIO_MAXIMO
            ]);
            if ($validatedData->fails())
            {
                //return  $validatedData->errors();
                return  $this->errorResponse("Ingrese las palabras clave y suba el archivo mayor o igual a 4 MB", 400);
            }
            $archivo = $request->file('archivo');
            $contenido = file_get_contents($archivo);
            $respuesta = $this->performFileStoreRequest('archivo', $contenido, [
                'tipo'      => 'desa',
                'extension' =>  $archivo->getClientOriginalExtension()
            ]);
            $respuesta = json_decode($respuesta);
            $path = $respuesta->data;

            $Adjunto = AtAdjuntoInterno::find($id_adjunto);
            $Adjunto->v_palabras_clave  = $request->v_palabras_clave ? $request->v_palabras_clave:null;
            $Adjunto->v_ruta_adjunto  = $path;
            $Adjunto->save();
            return $this->validResponse($Adjunto,Response::HTTP_OK,"Adjunto actualizado");
        }

    }
```

Funciona en el postman, el detalle es que cuando envio masivamente ya no me funciona, cual seria el problema, lo envio esta forma:
$this->subirAdjunto($request,$Adjunto->n_id)
donde $Adjunto es el objeto creado, gracias por sus comentarios.
Saludos

Comment: Para que sea masivo tu request debería tener un `array` de archivos. ¿Por qué tendrías que llamar múltiples veces a un método del controller? Si recibe un request en cada llamada, no es masivo. Por otro lado, deberías adjuntar el error que obtienes.

Answer (score 0):

Si es masivo, aca hago eso:

```
 if($request->adjuntos and count($request->adjuntos) > 0) {
                foreach ($request->adjuntos as $valor) {
                    $Adjunto = $this->guardarAdjuntoCorresInterna(
                        $Carta->n_id,
                        $valor['n_id_tipo_corres'],
                        $valor['n_id_sucursal'],
                        $valor['n_id_copia'],
                        $nro_cite,
                        $valor['n_can'],
                        $request->user()->n_id,
                        $request->user()->n_id_area);
                        //return $request;
                        $this->subirAdjunto($request,$Adjunto->n_id);

                }
            }
```

No muestra ningun error, $request ahi se envia el metodo subirAdjunto